# Xcode code generation

Tags: xcode, code-generation

I was wondering if there is a tool (automator script or a third party) to generate code for simple scenarios like add another property. I don't like going to two or three places and write the same thing over and over again. instead I want to say "I want a new property of type int with name X" and it generates the lines in .h and .m files for me in one go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't actually used either, but [xobjc](http://github.com/holtwick/xobjc) is free (though requires you to do some code annotations) and [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html) looks interesting if somewhat complicated to setup.

Comment: Accessorizer is actually pretty simple even though it looks like the flight deck of a 747. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Accessorizer is very well regarded.

Comment: I tried both and ended up liking the xobjc better. mostly because it does things in one go (modifying .m and .h file in one go). another thing I liked about xobjc better was the fact that you can run it more than once without needing to remember which parts have been generated before. still I think Xcode is miles behind visual studio...